# Unable to collect data from my PostController using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to create a feature on my web application that allows the user to see the posts between two dates. However, I am having problems trying to pass data from my database to my blade template. Instead of retrieving the created_at date of the post I receive the date "1/01/1970" and the job number does not appear.

[image]

First I added the routes in my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/search', function () {
    return view('search');
});

Route::post('/select', 'PostController@getDate');
```

In my PostController.php file, I added my getDate Function:

```
public function getDate(Request $request){
        $posts = DB::table('jobs')
                ->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->fdate, $request->sdate])
                ->get();

        $posts->created_at = $request->created_at;
        $posts->job_number = $request->job_number;
        return view('result', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }
```

My search.blade.php which is the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/select">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>First Date:</label>
       <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fdate">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Second Date:</label>
       <input type="date" class="form-control" name="sdate">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Post Between" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

My result.blade.php file which shows the post.

```
@if(count( $posts )>0)
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Date created</th>
                        <th>Job Number</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($posts as $post)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ date('j/m/Y', strtotime($posts->created_at)) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $posts->job_number }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            @else
                <h3 class="text-center">No Post from Selected Range</h3>
            @endif
```

I am honestly confused, I have used the correct variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are appending properties to a collection object not to each element

```
$posts->created_at = $request->created_at;
$posts->job_number = $request->job_number;
```

to add these properties to each element you should use map() or loop the elements.

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $post->created_at = $request->created_at;
    $post->job_number = $request->job_number;
}
```

you should use the single post not the whole array to get the date

change

```
<td>{{ date('j/m/Y', strtotime($posts->created_at)) }}</td>
```

with

```
<td>{{ date('j/m/Y', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</td>
```

same stuff for the `{{ $posts->job_number }}` -> `{{ $post->job_number }}`